# Использование where в связях Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

У меня есть 2 таблицы
Table Category
id name page_id
1 Happy 1
2 Luck 2

Table Page
id active
1 0
2 1

Model `Category` пример связи с моделью Page

```
public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Page');
    }
```

**Мне нужно вывести все категории у которых активна страница.** Я пробовал разными способомами но везде выдает ошибку.

```
Category::whereNotNull('page_id')
                ->with('page')
                ->where('page.active', 1)
                ->get()
```

И так пробовал

```
Category::whereNotNull('page_id')
                    ->with(['page' => function ($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
            }])
                    ->get()
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: В первом случае  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'page.active' in 'where clause' .. во втором просто ничего не происходит

Comment: Второй вариант ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Второй вариант выдает что активные что неактивные

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь `whereHas` нужно использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Category::whereNotNull('page_id')
                    ->with(['page'])
                    ->whereHas('page', function($query){
                           $query->where('active', 1);
                    })
                    ->get()
```

Извините если что не так пишу с телефона.

Comment: `whereNotNull('page_id')` не лишнее?

Comment: Вам виднее. page_id может быть NULL?

Comment: Да может, потому что есть словарь с категориями, но у категории может и не быть своей страницы, по этой причине и выбираем где есть точно страница, а потом где она точно активирована.

Comment: Выдает пока что "Undefined variable: query" пытаюсь понять почему

Comment: Поправил код выше

Comment: А в чем ошибка была?

Comment: В названии переменной. Все работает?

Comment: Вроде да, красота